# Can multiple get function calls be fired at the same time from different threads

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading, get

Suppose that I make several GET requests via jQuery's `get` function call. Will the callbacks provided as an argument to these function calls be fired in the same thread or can they be called at the same time, so I need some kind of synchronization for shared variables?

Comment: Can fire off numerous requests ... order they return though will be unknown since they are asynchronous. You need to provide more details on objective

Comment: The callbacks are called in order (although unknown) and not in parallel. Unless you use Workers or something like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is javascript single-threaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726098/is-javascript-single-threaded)

Comment: Normally javascript is single threaded. All your code will run in the same thread. The only exception to that is webworkers. However webworkers are designed such that synchronization is never necessary since you are never able to access the same memory from two different threads at the same time.

Comment: Duplicate [Is JavaScript multithreaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663125/is-javascript-multithreaded) ?

Comment: check here if it helps  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done